# Viewcontroller is blank when calling from button click in ios5

Tags: objective-c, ios

button click of  view controller shows a the blank view  when i create an instance of view controller which does not have a nib file.

```
 - (IBAction)OK:(id)sender {
    mainViewController *main = [[mainViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:main animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: The nib file is what determines the view. If you want to create an instance of view controller with no nib file, then a blank view is the expected outcome.
What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to init it with a nib name:

```
mainViewController *main = [[mainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: as he said, he has no .nib. so this answer is not helpful to him.